# Compiling PlayN Flash samples

Tags: java, maven, playn

I've been following [this](https://github.com/consiliens/blog/wiki/Compiling-PlayN-Flash) guide to get playn up and running in eclipse indigo. Hit some major bumps along the way (the largest being swithing to gwt 2.3) but I've managed to get it compiling the as files. The problem is when it starts to create the swf I get this flash compilation error:

```
C:\Users\ted\AppData\Local\Temp\1351877287607-0\testsgameflash.as(145): col: 220 Error: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 1.

function $replace_0(this$static,from,to){var regex;if(from<256){regex=toPowerOfTwoString(from);regex='\\x'+'00'.substring(regex.length)+regex}else{regex=String.fromCharCode(from)}return this$static.replace(RegExp(regex,'g'),String.fromCharCode(to))}

C:\Users\ted\AppData\Local\Temp\1351877287607-0\testsgameflash.as(146): col: 131 Error: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 1.

function $replaceAll(this$static,regex,replace){replace=__translateReplaceString(replace);return this$static.replace(RegExp(regex,'g'),replace)}
```

It looks like it is casting the value as 'RegExp' instead of creating a new instance of RegExp. I'm not sure where the mess up is and I just wondering what I can do to fix it and get everything compiled

Comment: Also, if anyone has a better step by step to get this up and running on Eclipse with a build to flash that actually works, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You failed at step 10 in that guide? Can you go through the steps you've taken in more detail?

Comment: The compiler is finding the flex sdk. I thought there might be something wrong with that as well but I played around and when the path the flex sdk is wrong, its a different error. But yes it is failing at step 10. What would you like for info about? I'm doing everything exactly how it is said in the guide but I am getting the above error